# SQLite Error 19: 'NOT NULL constraint failed' - Are strings nullable by default in .NET6/C# 8?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, migration, nullable-reference-types

I am having this issue after migrating my project from .NET 5 to .NET 6. I am using the latest version of SQLite as the database.

Visual Studio seems to be assuming that `string` is no longer nullable by default. Whenever Entity Framework tries to write to a field that is not a primary or foreign key I get the error `SQLite Error 19: 'NOT NULL constraint failed`. In .NET 5 I was not getting this error.

I also noticed that VS 2022 Intellisense has a green indicator line under each of the property names that cause this error. It states `Non-nullable property must contain a non null-value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring the property as nullable.`

Example of code the causes the error:

```
    [Table("ApplicationUser")]
    public class ApplicaitonUser : IdentityUser
    {
        // Inherited properties https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/customize-identity-model?view=aspnetcore-6.0
        [Key]
        public new int Id { get; set; } // every other property causes the SQLite 19 error
        
        [PersonalData]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [PersonalData]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        
        [PersonalData]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [PersonalData]
        public string PreferredName { get; set; }

        // Address Table Foreign Key relationship navigation property 
        [PersonalData]
        ICollection<UsAddress> UsAddresses { get; set; }


    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Nullable Aware Context

No, in .Net 6/C#8 Microsoft introduced "*nullable aware context*". When enabled, this context makes strings not-nullable by default. To be nullable then requires a nullable designation, like other types. This is useful for testing, etc...  And is more consistent with a strongly typed framework.

This feature can be turned on and off using the `<nullable>enable</nullable` or `<nullable>disable</nullable>` attribute in the Project file. Since the feature is disabled by default, the attribute can also be removed to disable it.

[Nullable contexts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#nullable-contexts)

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

*In a nullable aware context:*

- *A variable of a reference type `T` must be initialized with non-null,
  and may never be assigned a value that may be null.*
- *A variable of a reference type `T?` may be initialized with null or
  assigned null, but is required to be checked against null before
  de-referencing.*
- *A variable `m` of type `T?` is considered to be non-null when you apply
  the null-forgiving operator, as in `m!`.*

*The distinctions between a non-nullable reference type `T` and a nullable reference type `T?` are enforced by the compiler's interpretation of the preceding rules. A variable of type `T` and a variable of type `T?` are represented by the same .NET type.*

[Nullable reference types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-reference-types)

Examples:

```
string notNullable = "Hello";
string? nullable = default;
notNullable = nullable!; // null forgiveness
```

Additional information:

[Learn techniques to resolve nullable warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-warnings)

[Update a codebase with nullable reference types to improve null diagnostic warnings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-migration-strategies)